# Как построить правильный SQL запрос?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Прошу помощи с построением SQL запроса. Имеются две таблицы:

Первая:

```
ID каталога | Название каталога
1 | К1                 
2 | К2   
3 | К3
```

Вторая:

```
ID подкаталога | Название подкаталога
1 | ПК1                 
2 | ПК2   
3 | ПК3
```

, связанные через третью таблицу:

```
ID каталога | ID подкаталога
1 | 2                 
1 | 2   
1 | 3
```

При выборе "К1", список заполняется следующими подкаталогами: "ПК2", "ПК3".
Необходимо построить запрос, выводящий список подкаталогов, принадлежащих выбранному каталогу.

Не могу понять, как построить данный запрос, с SQL знаком плохо, до этого работал с БД, созданными через record/динамическим списком (Pascal, Delphi).

**Дополнение:**
Связаны таблицы по ID.

Comment: @QisQa, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @QisQa Уточните, как организована у вас база. Как у вас идёт связь между каталогом и подкаталогом. У вас в третьей таблице данные записаны в формате (столбец1,ряд1-столбец2,ряд1;столбец1,ряд2-столбец2,ряд2;):журнал1-каталог1; журнал1-каталог2  
  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решён. Использовал следующий запрос:

```
SELECT SubgenreName FROM subgenres 
WHERE SubgenreId IN 
(
    SELECT SubgenreId FROM genres_relations WHERE GenreId IN 
        (SELECT GenreId FROM genres 
         WHERE GenreName='+#39+dbgrdGenres.SelectedField.AsString+#39+')
)
```

Comment: Первое, плюсующим. Внутренний селект во внутреннем селекте - это разве хорошо?

Второе. Не проще ли это все сделать через JOIN`ы? Тов. @Andy92 показал пример. Его надо просто адаптировать под вашу базу. `DECLARE` можно убрать, заменив переменную вашим значением.

Третье. А чем каталог отличается от подкаталога (или жанр от поджанра)? И почему нет подкаталога подкаталога? Может быть стоит не разделять их на разные сущности, а свести все в одну таблицу: к первой таблице добавляем поле "parent_genre" и по нему строим иерархию.

Тогда выборка будет: `SELECT * FROM genres WHERE parent_genre = XXX`

Comment: Третье, продолжение. Сводить все в одну таблицу можно, только если у нас иерархия в виде дерева, а не в виде цепи. Т.е. если у жанра может быть только один родительский жанр.

Если у жанра может быть два и более родительских жанров, тогда можно избавиться только от одной таблицы `subgenres`. Т.е. в `genres_relations` оба id будут указывать на разные записи из `genres`. Но и в этом случае выборка будет простой:

    SELECT *
    FROM genres

    INNER JOIN genres_relations
    USING(GenreId)

    WHERE parent_genre = XXX

Comment: Большое спасибо за замечания. В дальнейшем учту. Пользуясь случаем, воспользуюсь "Третьим".

Answer (score 0):

Не тестил, поэтому напишите, работает или нет.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(5) ="K1"
SELECT namepodkat2 FROM Table2 JOIN table3 ON Table2.idpodcat2=Table3.idpodcat3 JOIN Table1 ON Table1.idcat1=Table3.idcat3 WHERE Table1.namecat=@name
```

DECLARE - это объявление переменной, которая будет вводиться. Для примера я ввёл К1.

Comment: @QisQa, вы бы уточнили какая СУБД используется и какую ошибку выдает